# Maintaining page number in DropDownList after postback to refresh server timeout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using .Net, VB and webforms.  I have a timer that pops up to allow the user to refresh their connection before the session expires.  Three of the pages in the app use the exact same style `DropDownList` in order to control the content that is being displayed.

When the user clicks "ok" to refresh a page that contains a `DropDownList`, the user gets an error that the `DropDownList` can only have one item selected.

How do I make the page render after postback in the same state that it was in pre-popup?

```js
Protected Sub ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'switch to page selected in pager
        Dim gvrPager As GridViewRow = gvSelectEvents.BottomPagerRow
        Dim ddlPages As DropDownList = DirectCast(gvrPager.Cells(0).FindControl("ddlPages"), DropDownList)

        gvSelectEvents.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex

        'populate your grid
        gvSelectEvents.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

```css
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TimeOutControl.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="UserControls_TimeOutControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var DoLogout = 1;
    var WarnMills;
    var TimeoutMills;
    var WarnDurationMills;
    var RedirectURL;
    var _timeLeft;

    function StartTimeout(TimeoutValue, WarnValue, WarnDuration, URLValue) {
        TimeoutMills = TimeoutValue;
        WarnMills = WarnValue;
        WarnDurationMills = WarnDuration;
        RedirectURL = URLValue;
        setTimeout('UserTimeout()', TimeoutMills);
        setTimeout('WarnTimeout()', WarnMills);
    }

    function UserTimeout() {
        if (DoLogout == 1) {
            top.location.href = RedirectURL;
        }
        else {
            DoLogout = 1;
            setTimeout('UserTimeout()', TimeoutMills);
            setTimeout('WarnTimeout()', WarnMills);
        }
    }

    function WarnTimeout() {
        _timeLeft = (WarnDurationMills / 1000);
        updateCountDown();
        $find('mdlSessionTimeout').show();
    }

    function updateCountDown() {
        var min = Math.floor(_timeLeft / 60);
        var sec = _timeLeft % 60;
        if (sec < 10)
            sec = "0" + sec;

        document.getElementById("CountDownHolder").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

        if (_timeLeft > 0) {
            _timeLeft--;
            setTimeout('updateCountDown()', 1000);
        }
    }

    function PreserveSession() {
        DoLogout = 0;
        __doPostBack('btnPreserveSession', '');
    }
</script>
```

```html
<PagerTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/firstpage.gif"
                            CommandArgument="First" CommandName="Page" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/prevpage.gif"
                            CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" />
                        <span style="color: White;">Page</span>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged1">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <span style="color: White;">of</span>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPageCount" runat="server" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/nextpage.gif"
                            CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/lastpage.gif"
                            CommandArgument="Last" CommandName="Page" />
                    </PagerTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to refresh the page to keep the session active. Instead, you can just use AJAX to call a method in an .asmx file *which has `EnableSession:=True`*.

An example of the code for that:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class SessionKeepAlive
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    ' this function is to called every 19 minutes from the Master page
    ' to keep the session alive.
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    <Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)> _
    Public Function Check() As String
        If HttpContext.Current.Session("username") Is Nothing Then
            Return "expired"
        Else
            Return "ok"
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

And if you were using an `<asp:ScriptManager>`, the JavaScript for the AJAX could look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                               
    //<![CDATA[                                                                                           
    var keepAlive = function() {                                                                          
        Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke("SessionKeepAlive.asmx", "Check", true, {}, SessionKeepAlive_Callback);
    }                                                                                                     

    function SessionKeepAlive_Callback(result, eventArgs) {                                               
        if (result != 'ok') {                                                                         
            alert('Your session has timed out.\nPlease log in again.');                           
            window.location = 'login.aspx';                                                       
        };                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                     
    // Set 19 minute .NET session keep alive timer...                                                     
    window.setInterval(keepAlive, 19 * 60 * 1000);                                                        
    //]]>                                                                                                 
</script>
```

You might choose a different way of calling the method in the web service, e.g. by using jQuery.

Comment: @rogerdeuce Please feel free to say why my answer didn't work out for you - I might be able to offer an adjustment or alternative.

Comment: I've had multiple issues implementing this fix, I now do have it all implemented correctly but, it's not actually extending the session.  Please see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622583/web-service-returns-expected-value-but-doesnt-extend-the-session-timer

Comment: @rogerdeuce You will need *some* session variable, it doesn't have to be named "username" as in `Session("username")`, just something that you set when the user logs in successfully.

Comment: I picked up on that, I'm using "strValid" now which is set when the user initially logs in,  Session("strValid") = "Valid"

Comment: @rogerdeuce If you read the documentation for the [Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383814%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you will see how to check for errors, which will help debug it.

Comment: ok looks like I have it working now, a problem with the javaScript after the webService call.  Thanks!

Comment: @rogerdeuce You're welcome :) Now you've got the Javascript working, you might want it to adapt it to force a logout after, say, 4 hours for those people who leave their computer left on when they go home/whatever.

Comment: Have you noticed when using this implementation that the timer seems to change?  for example my server is set to a 20 minute session, and my pop up happens 5 minutes before the user is logged out.  However once the pop up happens the first time, it seems random as to how long you have until the pop up shows up again.  Sometimes the popup doesn't show up for 30 minutes the second time and sometimes it takes 5 minutes for it to show up again.

Comment: @rogerdeuce Have you arranged your Javascript so that `window.setInterval` is called only once? It *shouldn't* ever take longer than the interval you set, but I can imagine that if you had more than one `setInterval` then you could get popups more often. A good place to check when the function is being called is in the IIS server log.