# Ajax error using POST request with Ajax control tool kit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

My modal popup session timeout extender is misbehaving.

I'm trying to implement the solution given in my previous question ([Maintaining page number in DropDownList after postback to refresh server timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166962/maintaining-page-number-in-dropdownlist-after-postback-to-refresh-server-timeout)).

I am encountering an error:  An attempt was made to call the method \u0027Check\u0027 using a POST request, which is not allowed.","  I've been researching the error and the simple solution seems to be to make the request not a post request.  I've tried removing runat="server", adding "return:false;" to the onClick, and adding "return false" to the script.

Is there a way to make this work?

My .asmx web file:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following    line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class SessionKeepAlive
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    <Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True)> _
    Public Function Check() As String
        If HttpContext.Current.Session("username") Is Nothing Then
            Return "expired"
        Else
            Return "ok"
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

My pop up html:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSessionTimeout" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;"
Width="300">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; background-color: #51516A" align="center">
                WARNING! Session About to Expire
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    Your session will time out in
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTimeoutCount" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    minutes. Click the ‘Continue’ button to keep working. 
                    When the timer reaches 0:00 your online session is no longer active.
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlCountDown" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <span id="CountDownHolder"></span>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <span style="text-align: center; display: block;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnPreserveSession" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Continue"/>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSessionTimeout" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnlSessionTimeout"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" BehaviorID="mdlSessionTimeout" DropShadow="false"
    OkControlID="btnPreserveSession" OnOkScript="PreserveSession()"     PopupControlID="pnlSessionTimeout">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

My ajax script call:

```
    function PreserveSession() {
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SessionKeepAlive.asmx/Check",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: checkAuthenticatedOk,
            error: checkAuthenticatedError
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change (UseHttpGet:=True), to False in order to use a POST request from AJAX.  UseHttpGet:=True can only be used with an AJAX GET request.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question. However, since you are using Telerik Ajax, you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

You can just use [Session Timeout Notification](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/sessiontimeout/defaultcs.aspx).

[image]

Comment: I looked into this, and we have the ajax control toolkit, and not the telerik ajax ui.  I am quite new to this and maybe I misunderstood something, but that's what it said when I tried to implement this solution

Comment: I do not see Telerik in your code; it might be just [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/). Btw, how do you know you application use Telerik?

Comment: you are correct @Win sorry for the confusion I must have seen it in one of my other projects and the name got stuck in my head.